# Al activar Ngrok OAuth la página da error de fetch

Tags: nodejs, fetch

Estuve haciendo una página web y me gustaría que tuviera un sistema de OAuth con Google para que solo ciertas personas con la cuenta respectiva puedan acceder.
Todo funciona correctamente, hasta que inicio sesión e intento acceder a algún apartado. Cuando termina de cargar el apartado, en vez de darme el resultado me da un error de que no se ha podido encontrar (fetch).

Estoy utilizando BareServer y ExpressJS, por si sirve de algo.

Espero que me puedan ayudar y gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.